# How do I change permissions/ownership of .config file from "root" to me ("username")?

Tags: permissions, config

So I'm running into this error every time I run a command in terminal (using Visual Code Studio) while doing anything within a git repository.
[Terminal Git Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfAFc.png)

I did some digging and found out the owner of the .config file is "root" and not me "username" (see second screenshot)[Root is owner of .config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWBt8.png)

Do you know how to change the ownership to me so I stop getting this warning message? I ran a command I found on here "sudo chown -R $(username) .config" but it wasn't recognized, then asked me for a password and wouldn't let me type anything so I closed out of terminal.

I'm new to all this and coming from a construction background and going back to school so layman's terms would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: this is not a Git issue, it's a Unix/Linux file ownership and permissions issue. Git is simply stumbling over your system's file protection policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo chown $USER path/to/.config
```

is the correct command. `sudo` asks for your password (the same one you use to login to the `$USER` account); for security reasons the password isn't echoed, you just have to input it blindly and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Check if environment variables are not empty: `echo $LOGNAME` ? `echo $USER` ? `echo $USERNAME` ? Or just put your login name in the command: `sudo chown -R username ~/Users/username/.config`

Comment: Thanks that did it! Took me a minute to figure out the correct path and enter the command correct but thats it, everything looks great. 

Thanks so much!